# придать ускорение вместо замедления падающему мячу

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

имеется падающий шар. Проблема в том что он падает с замедлением, а требуется с ускорением. Помогите с решением. Заранее спасибо)

```js
window.onload = () => {
const out = document.getElementById('out') 
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
let metr = 0.1;
let seconds = 1000;

const speed = 9.8;
const vector = { x: 0, y: 1}
const position = {x: 300, y: 0}
function draw(timeDelta) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600)
  const dX = (vector.x * (metr / (timeDelta / seconds) * speed) || 0)
  const dY = (vector.y * (metr / (timeDelta / seconds) * speed) || 0)
  
  position.x += dX
  position.y += dY

  out.innerText = `${position.x}, ${position.y}, ${dX}, ${dY}`

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(position.x, position.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

draw();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background: gray
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="out">Out</div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вместо `const dX = (vector.x * (metr / (timeDelta / seconds) * speed) || 0)` для ускорения по Х нужно `const dX = (vector.x * (metr * (timeDelta / seconds) * speed) || 0)` и соответственно вместо  `const dY = (vector.y * (metr / (timeDelta / seconds) * speed) || 0)` для ускорения по У нужно `const dY = (vector.y * (metr * (timeDelta / seconds) * speed) || 0)`

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk спасибо